# How deep does one split up a big project in different repositories?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, teamcity, gitlab

I recently migrated a Subversion repository to Git. All went well. I used the git philosophy of making separate repositories of each module of the software. But now the developers tell me that they often do work that changes something in the main app and one of the modules, that makes two commits, where it would have made sense to do it in one commit. 
This tells me that the modules aren't really separate from the main app. So one big repository would make sense. 
On the other hand, our main product is open source and some of the modules too, and we sync those repositories to Github and Sourceforge. But there are also a few closed source modules, that really shouldn't go outside. So they *have to* be in a separate repo in our internal Gitlab.

They ask me to make two big (svn-style) repositories: one for open source and one for closed source. I on the other hand (QA & release management) feel like it's related to how the different parts interact and how you cannot change anything in one place without having to change something else in another place. But I am not a full-time developer and I haven't digged into the depth of this particular code base.

Another argument: the software exist in Java and C# flavors. The Java version was previously built from svn in different Jenkins jobs, one for each module (so split git repos made perfect sense from a CI point of view), while the C# version is built in one big TeamCity job (lends to one big, svn-style repo).

I know that the general git practice is to split things up, but how deep do you have to split?

Comment: Are the modules registered as git submodules? why does the devs say that "it makes sense to make just one commit"? 2 commits can be and describing as one with git modules, and keeping the main/module code separated from each other would make the repository history tiddier. On the other hand, if the repos have heavy dependencies, merging may not be a bad idea. Finally, I think a team should adapt the tools to their needs and not just stick to best practices for the sake of it. If they think their workflow will be greatly improved by merging the repositories, maybe it is the way to go.

Comment: No, they are not registered as git submodules. I'll have to figure out how git submodules work in combination with the git-flow tools.
The dependencies are only in one direction, it is possible to have the main app without any of the modules. Some of the team think that it does make sense to split up the repos if most of the commits are only to a module and don't change anything in the main app. The same for our end users, most of them only use the main app.

Comment: Another thing, in subversion one of the modules was already split off in the past to a separate project on sourceforge with a separate repo. 2 of the other modules were kept in the same repo as the main app for historical reasons, but they are at the same level as the one module that was already split off.
Yeah, it's a bit of a mess, and I tried to bring back a bit more consistency.

Comment: Submodules are not suitable for our workflow. Subtrees on the other hand, may be a better solution. We can work in either one big repo or in individual small repos, and we can even include the closed source stuff while still keeping it separate from the outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a "lot" on how many independent modules you have an how many of them move together frequently. In our team, we had 4 different java modules(Which moved independently), a C# code base, a library of perl modules, DB artefacts and a suite of shell scripts.

Our codebase has been around for 4-5 years , which leads to a lot of code, commits and unused branches. Even though git is fast and has a lot of engineering for large repos , after a period of time it is unhealthy to have so much cruft in the VCS(git/svn/) for whatever reasons. Also, if we have independent repos it is easier to merge and also reset-hard whenever a developer messes up the repository (it does happen infrequently) without affecting other repos.

Also, we had a similar dependency between our C# and java API layer, where there were times where commits needed to be made in both repos, but we calculated that number of individual commits in either API or C# layer were far more than coordinated commits, so moving into multiple repos made sense for us. It also helped that all our modules are not tightly coupled and have sane in-house versioning systems that helps us maintian them in a micro-services type of architecture.

You can setup technology related build/test/CI stacks irrespective of whether you have multiple repos/single repos , so that should not be a deciding factor in what you want to do

Comment: The core and the modules are (almost) always released together, but then we still have the split between open and closed source.
Easier merges and resets are strong arguments in our case.
I made a combined repository with git subtree and at first glance it appears that there are some coordinated commits between core and modules, but most of them are indeed individual. But it's true that we still can do a lot more to reduce the tight coupling. That's a work in continuous progress! :)

Comment: For the open and closed source code, I believe some firms open up their open source code to the public through github. I would specifically suggest keeping the open source code in a different repo so that if someone forks off it and creates a pull request you can always merge it back into your repo without having to figure out submodules and another associated processes.It is a pretty good logical separation to have